# CSS one pager layout

Tags: html, css

I am struggeling with my basic layout for a one pager.

Here is my code:

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section-single>.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10%;
}

.section-double>.content-left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
}

.section-double>.content-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: black;
}

#section1 {
  background: green;
}

#section2 {
  background: red;
}

#section3 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-single" id="section1">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?..."></iframe>
  <a href="#section2"><span class="arrow">section 2</span></a>
</section>
<section class="section-double" id="section2">
  <div class="content-left" id="div1">
  </div>
  <div class="content-right" id="div2">
</section>
<section class="section-double" id="section3">
  <div class="content-left" id="div3">
  </div>
  <div class="content-right" id="div4">
</section>
```

Here is how it should look like:
[image: Baisc layout]

As you see in the css, each section should have the full screen size available and the divs should have both 50% of the page. However, the divs positioning is not working as expected (checked by the background propertie in `.section-double > .content-left`   and `.section-double > .content-right`.

Can you help me?

Comment: You haven't closed the `.content-right` divs. And i would go with Pete's answer as flexbox supports responsibility, while float doesn't on default.

Comment: you can use bootstrap grids

Comment: I know, but i dont want to use bootstrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this layout:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;          /* set the container to flex */
  flex-wrap:wrap;        /* allow children to wrap */
  flex-direction:row;    /* line up children in a row - default value not needed */
}
.container > div {
  min-height:100vh;        /* moved as per comments below */
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;   /* demo borders only */
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
    section one
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    div 1
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    div 2
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    div 3
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    div 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To make this look like in the picture, simply wrap each div-group into the container.

Comment: @ItFreak ah right, wasn't sure if you wanted each section to be 100vh or the whole thing to be 100vh.   Instead of wrapping each section, I would move the min-height to the `.container > div` (I use min height as if one of your divs exceed the height, then it can grow - also growing any partner div on the same row

Comment: Yea, thats possible too

Comment: Still using flex-direction: row; ... @ItFreak It's by default so you don't have to include it.

Comment: @VXp best to show these things so people know that it is there (and being used even if it is the default value), especially when using wrap

Comment: Don't agree, first they should only try display: flex; to see how the flex-items align, which is inline, then the result after flex-wrap: wrap;, if of course the condition is met, no reason to include any defaults, ever.

Answer (score 2):

One thing, you have unclosed tags in your html.

```
<section class="section-single" id="section1">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?..."></iframe>
  <a href="#section2"><span class="arrow">section 2</span></a>
</section>
<section class="section-double" id="section2">
 <div class="content-left" id="div1">
  div 1 section 2
 </div>
 <div class="content-right" id="div2">
  div 2 section 2
 </div>
</section>
<section class="section-double" id="section3">
 <div class="content-left" id="div3">
  div 1 section 3
 </div>
 <div class="content-right" id="div4"> 
  div 2 section 3
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but the divs inside the sections should have the same height as the parents section (so each section has 100% of the size and the divs split into left and right)

Answer (score 1):

i've updated your css, kindly check below

```
<section class="section-single" id="section1">
  hello
  <a href="#section2"><span class="arrow">Section 1</span></a>
  </section>
<section class="section-double" id="section2">
  <div class="content-left" id="div1">Div 1
</div>
<div class="content-right" id="div2"> Div 2 </div>
</section>
  <section class="section-double" id="section3">
  <div class="content-left" id="div3"> Div 3
</div>
<div class="content-right" id="div4"> Div 4 </div>
</section>
```

div2 and div4 close tags were missing

```
section{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section-single > .arrow{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10%;
}



.section-double div{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;

}

#section1{
  background: green;
}
#section2{
  background: red;
}
#section3{
  background: yellow;
}
```

instead of making left and right content. i've just added

```
.section-double div{
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;

    }
```

this makes both the div 50% and float makes them in one line.

check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/8jsnpw4o/9/